# Alias for bash not working (using bash and edited bash_profile with restart)

Tags: bash, shell

```
/bin/bash
/bin/csh
/bin/dash
/bin/ksh
/bin/sh
/bin/tcsh
/bin/zsh
Tony$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
Tony$ cd Dev/operation-fix/
:operation-fix Tony$ gst
-bash: gst: command not found

ALIASES in bash_profile in ~:
alias gst="git status"
```

Gone through a few other stackoverflows but the issue persists? Not sure why I am using bash_profile for other aspects of development like hidden environment variables and such and works fine. Am I not using the alias correctly? Thanks

Comment: `.bash_profile` is only sourced for login shells. Are you in a login shell?

Comment: If you are on Linux and opening, say, an `xterm`, you are starting a non-login interactive shell that inherits environment variables from the original login shell started when you logged in, but aliases are *not* inherited. Aliases should be defined in `.bashrc` to ensure they are defined in all interactive shells.

Comment: ok thank you @chepner I didnt know about login shells. Looking them up now and will moev the aliases over to bashrc.